# Insert data into an empty spreadsheet (without a header) with OleDb

Tags: c#, linq, oledb

Is it possible to insert data into a spreadsheet using linq and OleDb and NOT Interop. For example:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO `Sheet2$` (`A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`,`F`) VALUES (1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)", connection);
```

Or

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO `Sheet2$` VALUES (1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)", connection);
```

If I try to run any of thesee commands I get the following errors:

Unknown column. - for the first one

Number of query values and destination fields are not the same. - for the second one

Reminder I want to achieve this using only OleDb.

UPDATE:

To be more clear, I need to insert data without an existing table, because I need to insert variable number of columns in each row. That is the actual root of my problem. Creating a table does not solve my problem, as I don't know how many columns I'll need to insert. Sorry for not being clear from the start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to a blank excel sheet with ADO.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258678/writing-to-a-blank-excel-sheet-with-ado-net)

Comment: @Plutonix I edited the question sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to insert data into excel pattern?

For example, insert one row with data manually:
AF1 | AF2 | AF3 | AF4 | ... | AFn
As more, as you can.

After this, you can fill this sheet with command and parameters like:
@"insert into [sheetName] ([AF1], [AF2], [AF3], [AF4] ... [AFn]) VALUES (@AF1, @AF2, @AF3, @AF4 ... @AFn)";

After that, you can delete first row.